# How could I update a wiki page from a formated txt file?

Tags: web, wiki, mediawiki

I need to update info in a template on a wiki page with info from a specially formatted text file. I have access to the actual wiki database if that is necessary.

Basically, how do I update a wiki page programatically? What tools do I need? etc.

EDIT1:Wiki is running on VMS so things like .NET (and anything windows/microsoft oriented) are generally out.

EDIT2: I need to be able to edit part of the wiki page, not just replace the entire page with whats in the text file. OR, if I could update the text file to be current with the wiki, then edit the info in the text file that I want updated via my DCL script and then update the page in its entirety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have a look at [Wikipedia:Creating a bot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Creating_a_bot#Open-source_bots). I personally have had good experience with the .NET wiki bot (link in wikipedia article above, or search in sourceforge).

**EDIT**: concerning the .NET wiki bot specifically, you'll need to simply login to your wiki, then update the text (after reading your text file.)

Naturally, you'll need .NET development environment.

For other bots, the process is probably the same, but I really have no experience.

Comment: Actually just found some info on Perl based and Python based bots. .NET could be troublesome since the wiki is running on VMS(its ancient, I know)